# How to send data from 2 different forms in a single table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table named users and it has fields namely -> id, username, fullname, email, password, gender, country, state, city, activated(0 by default).

I have created a form 1 for accepting the user input for username, fullname, email, password and gender. This data is successfully inserted in the table.

I have created second form in a new php page for accepting the user input for country, state and city, but when I try to insert the second form's data in the table, it doesn't inserts at all.

Can you please help me out ?

Thank You.

Comment: Hard to tell without any code your showing.

Comment: can you show the code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use `UPDATE usere SET .... WHERE id=$id` at the second insert to update the existing entry.

Otherwise show some code!